# How to Send HTTP_REQUEST without encoding?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, ruby-on-rails-3.2, typhoeus

I want to send a request without encoding the params. Because my API is expecting the params as auth_token but while sending request it got encoded to auth%5Ftoken. Because of this its throwing error. Please help me to send request without encoding. I am using gym Typhoeus to send http requests.

MY CODE:

```
 data = {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
 header =  { "Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept"=>"application/json"}
 request = Typhoeus::Request.post("www.example.com",:body=> data.to_json,:headers => header)
```

Comment: please post log output or some other info about your post request.